# Custom section header with static UITableView cells

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm wondering if it is possible to handle custom section headers when using static table cells. It doesn't seem possible through Interface Builder... the datasource is not called, so the method `viewForHeaderInSection` is never called too.

I'm not interested in workarounds like using a cell as section header.

Answer (score 0):

Method `viewForHeaderInSection` is part of `UITableViewDelegate` protocol so you can adopt it and use that method for your section header.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check whether you have made a connection between the *interface builder* and your *ViewController*.

`delegate` and `datasource` should be connected.